# How to version a RFT project

Tags: tools

Version control for test assets is a no brainer, but dropping a Rational Functional Tester directly into VC hasn't been easy.  Attempting to use a tool like Subversion with multiple users modifying the same project has exposed issues with corrupted object maps and required additional reformatting of these maps when committing to avoid this problem.  Can anyone provide a good method or tool that they use to keep their RFT project versioned properly?

UPDATE: One of the major issues we noticed with using Subversion and the RFT project was that merging changes to the object map by more than one person had problems.  The map is kept as a single line XML file, so when two different resources change it and Subversion attempts the merge, it fails when comparing the two single line XML files. We discovered a way around this with some reformatting, but I was hoping for a more elegant solution.

Comment: I know the time has passed lol...
I am facing the same problem here. 2 or more resources cannot modify the same object map in SVN. the unique row xml didnt allow us to merge itens.
i hope IBM think about it someday.

Answer (score 2):

I used SVN successfully with RFT Java test scripts. The Subclipse plugin does work however you need to ensure you version control all the files, not just the Java files themselves. Tortoise SVN also works well outside of Eclipse. That was over a year ago so I am a bit rusty I'm afraid.

Because several files are updated automatically when you are editing scripts, deleting object etc it makes it difficult for multiple users to merge their changes esily.

Unfortunately there doesn't appear to be any info on DeveloperWorks regarding version control for RFT.

Hope this helps.

Comment: We used a similar setup, but when committing object maps, Subversion saw them as a single line XML file.  We converted the file to a multi-line format, but whenever we changed the map, RFT wrote it out as a single line again.  Did you experience anything like this?

Comment: I remember it being single line, I never bothered changing it.  Does it matter for anything other than readability?  The object map is a file the RFT manages internally so you shouldn't really need to manually edit it.

Comment: If the map was modified by more than one resource and subversion attempted to merge the maps on commit, the single line map would fail during the diff.  I'll add this to the question to give a bit more detail.

Comment: Sorry I didn't have to deal with that issue. On a side note, we had a separate object map for each screen of our applications, sometimes two or three depending on complexity of the application. This meant that we very rarely had two people automating tests in the same area at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Hi We use Rational Team Concert internally and it automatically knows which files to control and we have no problems with it. I guess that because it is Rational working with Rational Functional Tester the problems in other version control tools do